# ORDER BY column = value desc|asc

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I found this piece of code a while ago, and I don't seem to find any explanation about how it really works:

```
SELECT account_id from accounts order by account_id = 100;
```

So, I know what `order by [column] desc|asc` does to the result set. But I don't seem to find the explanation for giving a value to the `[column]` and how that affects the result set. It's clearly affected, but I don't seem to find a pattern.

Comment: Rows with "account_id = 100" will be sorted at the end, since true > false.

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting your query using an explicit `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT account_id
FROM accounts
ORDER BY CASE WHEN account_id = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

You will observe that all records having `account_id != 100` will appear before all records where this is true.  When you use:

```
ORDER BY account_id = 100
```

Then you are ordering by the boolean equality itself.  So, when *not* true, it would evaluate to zero, and when true would evaluate to one.

Comment: So, basically the other rows will be returned in the order that they appear in the table? And only the row/rows with the value mentioned in the order by clause will be put at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Basically `ORDER BY` is of two types `ASC` and `DESC`
By Default it is `ASC`

Let us take an example

```sql
SELECT * from Person
ORDER BY Age DESC
```

Above query returns the Age of Persons in Descending Order

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports boolean types, which take on two values "true" and "false" (plus `NULL`, of course).  A boolean value is being used as the `order by` key.

The expression `account_id = 100` evaluates to "true" for account_id 100 and false for others (or `NULL`).

What does this do?  Well, "true" > "false" and the ordering is ascending.  Hence, the true value is ordered *after* all other values; account_id 100 goes at the end.  Well not quite the end.  `NULL` values are lastest -- they would go at the very end.

More commonly, this is done with a descending sort:

```
order by (account_id = 100) desc
```

This puts account 100 *first* in the list.

Note:  I put the expression in parentheses in such cases to make it clear that the intent really is to order by the expression.  That is, there is no typo.